# How to show the Title of a ShellContent in Xamarin.Forms xaml?

Tags: xamarin.forms

i need to show in a label the Title property of a ShellContent. Is it possible? Thanks!
This is the code for the item menu

```
    <FlyoutItem Title="My Places" Icon="icon_places.png">
        <ShellContent Route="MapsPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MapsPage}" Title="Ayto" />
    </FlyoutItem>

I tried with await DisplayAlert("Alert" . . .):

ShellContent.TitleProperty.PropertyName

and

ShellContent.Title

unsuccessfully
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `x:name` attribute to the xaml page.

Use `name.title` in the background code to get the name.

Here is the xaml code:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="My Places" Icon="icon_places.png">
    <ShellContent Title="Monkeys"
                  Icon="monkey.png"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MainPage}" x:Name="mytest"/>
</FlyoutItem>
```

Here is the background code:

```
var titile = mytest.Title;
```